# List c# The name "list.add" does not exist in this context

Tags: c#, wpf, list

So in school We are learning to use WPF for user interfaces and i've came along a problem in my c# code.

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
list.Add("asdfasdf");
```

Visual studio gives a couple of errors for "list.Add" but basicaly it says "The name 'list' does not exist in current context".

I have no idea whats wrong and would apreciate anyones help.

Comment: Build the solution and check the errors; you're missing a reference.

Comment: Just in case try: `List<string> list = new List<string> { "asdfasdf" };`

Comment: Do you have this code at class level ? `list.Add` part should be part of a method.

Comment: not enough info to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Not sure, but do you still have the issue if you rename your variable from "list" to something else?

Comment: Either you are redefining `List<T>`, or missing the `using System.Collections.Generic;` statement like others have said

Comment: If it were missing the using directive, the error would state `The type or namespace 'List' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`. Sounds to me like that is not in fact the issue but it's probably a problem of scope and OP isn't providing all of the *actual* code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think to be able to call the list.Add you have to call it from a function or a void (static void main() for example)

Comment: Not sure why this answer wasn't upvoted. This is correct. If you try to add things to the list outside of a method (like next to a globally defined list) it won't work. Move your Add to a method.

Answer (score 4):

I think you must add to your code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
```

Please add all your code if you want more help.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your explanation you seem to be missing a reference. Add this to where you reference your libraries.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
```